# API to share to all social media on one click

Tags: facebook, twitter, share, linkedin-api, social-media

I am working on an application,which allows the user to share his promos(promos are daily deals) to all social media in a single click.That is I want to connect his FB,twitter and Linkedin accounts and authorize **once** and later he can share it to his FB,twitter,linkkedin with a single share button and a message fiels to add custom messg.

Tried to find something online but there are only individual plugins which are mostly for login and not for connect.These sites **hootsuite** and **buffer app** have this feature but they dont provide it for third party apps.

Can anyone point to a library that has this feature to connect all the social media and then post to the user wall?

Comment: If you are planning to have those “deals” postes on _user_ timelines, then Facebook will basically consider this a spam app.

Comment: That is why i want it to be authorized by the user and it will be posted to his timeline,no one elses!

Comment: Well you better go read platform policies then. You are not allowed to post to a user timeline automatically, every single post has to be actively triggered by the user, and the content has to be a 100% user generated, i.e. typed in by the user.

Comment: You can try https://www.ayrshare.com for a universal social media API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no library, you have to program that on your own by using all the APIs of those Social Networks - which is what Hootsuite does. That´s why you have to authorize the Hootsuite App to make this work.

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs
- https://dev.twitter.com/
- https://developers.google.com/+/api/
- https://developer.linkedin.com/

Comment: Yes thats what I want to build.I have to authorize the user only once and not every time he wants to post to his wall.But I thought there is some API or library available which does this.Does hootsuite API help achieving this?Can I use their API to achieve it from my app? I have requested a developer access,waiting for approval.

Comment: I tried to find but did not get specific API for connecting account with FB.Does FB have a specific API to just connect and authorize the user,so I dont I have check it for every post

Comment: hootsuite is using the facebook api, you can´t use their code for your own app. take a look at the first link in my answer, the facebook docs are pretty good nowadays but you will have to read a lot. there is a section about login and access tokens and whatnot.

Comment: I have implemented the login using php sdk,but not sure if I can store some token on our side to authenticate the user after teh first connect.I am short on time and hence wanted to check if I can get some help.

Comment: maybe this will help: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: I just went through your post,I believe I will need the `Extended User Access Token` feature to make call for sharing data without authorization each time.Also,I will have to override the default share pop up of facebook as I want to have a custom msg box where user writes msg and it is submitted to all social media sites at a single click

Comment: you can´t override the share popup, you have to use api calls with the user token > see facebook docs (/me/feed)

Comment: I am not sure but I believe I should be able to test it on graph explorer by getting an access token! Please confirm.Also would simialr approach work for twitter and linkedin as well,I believe they too must have user access token

Comment: well...just try it. a main part of programming is trial and error ;) - twitter and linked in a are a bit different. you need to go through their dev docs too.

Comment: I am a bit confused,do I need a `access token` or `app token`.If I authorize the user using the app token and use the same extended token for all users,won't that work? Or do I need to get an access token for each user independently?

Comment: you really need to start reading the docs, make sure you understand what an access token is. it can be an app token, user token or page token. just open the link from my comment.

Comment: ok luschn I will! Thank you for your help! (Y)

Answer (score 2):

you can use shareholic api to share content across all social media.

https://shareaholic.com/api

Comment: I will try it! will need to check the level of customization it allows. our use case needs a few custom features